# Doctrine ResultSetMapping ignores entity

Tags: php, doctrine

In doctrine, I want to fetch multiple entities from a native query. But I can't workout how to do it.

I have 3 entities: `WBSOProject`, `Employee` and `WBSOBooking`. Employees can log their work hours through a `WBSOBooking` entity which couples the `Employee` with a `WBSOProject` and it has an extra field for the logged hours.

To generate an overview of the worked hours per employee per project I've written the following code:

```
$query = "
        select
            project.id as project_id,
            project.name,
            employee.id as employee_id,
            employee.bsn,
            employee.name,
            sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(wbsoBooking.total))) as balance
        from wbso_projects project
        inner join wbso_bookings as wbsoBooking on wbsoBooking.project_id = project.id
        inner join employees as employee on employee.id = wbsoBooking.employee_id
        group by project.year, project.name, employee.id, employee.name
    ";

    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm
        ->addEntityResult("Kloktijden\\Model\\Entities\\WBSOProject", "project")
        ->addFieldResult("project", "project_id", "id")
        ->addFieldResult("project", "name", "name")
        ->addEntityResult("Kloktijden\\Model\\Entities\\Employee", "employee")
        ->addFieldResult("employee", "employee_id", "id")
        ->addFieldResult("employee", "bsn", "bsn")
        ->addFieldResult("employee", "name", "name")
        ->addScalarResult("balance", "balance");

    $result = Model::getEntityManager()
        ->createNativeQuery($query, $rsm)
        ->getResult();
```

My desired result would be an array like this:

```
    array(
        [0] => array(
            [0] =>          Kloktijden\\Model\\Entities\\WBSOProject,
            [1] =>          Kloktijden\\Model\\Entities\\Employee,
            "balance"   =>  "00:00"
        )
    )
```

But somehow the `Employee` entity gets ignored, so my result looks like this:

```
    array(
        [0] => array(
            [0] =>          Kloktijden\\Model\\Entities\\WBSOProject,
            "balance"   =>  "00:00"
        )
    )
```

So, my question is: why doesn't my resultset contain the `Employee` entity? And how can I fix this?